# When can a continuous linear functional be minimized?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space (you can assume $X$ is locally convex if it makes any difference). Let $C \subset X$ be nonempty, and let $f$ be a continuous linear functional on $X$.

When does $f$ attain a minimum on $C$?

Obviously, if $C$ is compact, then it contains a minimizer of $f$ (and the linearity of $f$ is not required for this fact). But is there anything else we can say?

I am also familiar with the fact that lower semicontinuous functions can be minimized over compact sets, but here I am asking about properties of $C$ that guarantee continuous linear functionals can be minimized.

---

**Added** Theorem 2.32 in this [book](https://archive.siam.org/books/mo19/MO19_ch2.pdf) is interesting. It says that if $X = \mathbb R^n$ and $f$ is continuous and coercive, i.e.
$$\lim_{\| x \| \to \infty}f(x) = \infty,$$
then $f$ attains a minimum on $C$ provided only that $C$ is closed. I'm not sure if the proof will generalise to an infinite dimensional normed TVS.

Comment: You can weaken the hypothesis to $C$ being weakly compact.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yes. Was hoping for something better than that, but you're quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Corollaries 3.22 and 3.23 in the book “Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations” by H. Brezis. They talk about convex lower-semicontinuous functions.

**Edit**: The first one, for instance, implies that $f\in X^*$ attains its minimum if $C$ is convex, bounded and closed. But to be honest, I wouldn’t know how to generalize it to locally convex topological vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks. These results use the assumption that the space is reflexive in an essential way. In order to generalise the proof I mentioned in my Added section, we need closed balls to be weakly compact, which is equivalent to reflexiveness. For my problem, I can't assume that $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: I see. I don’t have much more to say, sorry. Maybe you could try to explain your problem a bit more in a new question to see which hypotheses one could try to assume.